# Chrome craps out displaying opengl xml

Tags: google-chrome

In chrome the site

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml

Does not look at all like it does in firefox. No graphics and lots of ugly text. There are some readable parts but it does not at all look correct by any stretch. It looks slightly better in incognito mode(no plugins) but still does not display correctly.

Does anyone know what the issue is? Someone said chrome can't deal with rss feeds or something which was related to xml files...

Comment: I have a similar problem. Seems to only be an issue with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Before I go into this, kudos to Chrome for optimizing web browsing speed and simplicity. The catch-22? Certain capabilities that are a *given* in other browsers have to be sacrificed in order to result in Chrome's overall optimization.

Now, if you are having issues with RSS feeds in Google Chrome, that's probably due to the unfortunate fact that Chrome can't display XML or RSS/Atom feeds without add-ons. Sometimes Chrome will try to hijack and open the feed the Google RSS Reader. There are ways to make it so the XML feed will be rendered in the browser. Try any app in Chrome that will display the "view" intent for feeds, such as [Feed Intent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/feed-intent-viewer/oceapojkdgeophkjdijkpbjifdnfimdh). Another option is the [RSS Subscription Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd). Lastly, take a look at this [XML Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xv-%E2%80%94-xml-viewer/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk).

Comment: These do not fix the problem: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/ and select any function. In ends up showing nonsense. Mainly it seems to show javascript code at the top and bottom as html and many of the graphical elements(matrices and vector notation) are not displayed correctly. I do not think this has anything to do with rss as these are not rss feeds but simply html pages. I'm simply trying to find a way to display the pages so they would appear correctly instead of having to use another browser. Installing the plugins you suggested changed nothing.